# first disable right click and then re-enable right click on same page using javascript

Tags: javascript, right-click

I want to achieve disable the first right click and then re-enable right click on the same page.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
  for(var id = 0; id < elements.length; ++id) { 
    elements[id].oncontextmenu = null; 
  }
</script>
/* this code will re-enable the right click */
```

```html
<html>
  <body oncontextmenu="return false;">
    
    <!-- This will disable right click -->
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cases when you want to enable and disable  the right click???

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question and your question is formatted in a wrong way. You'll probably get downvotes for this.

Comment: i have gallery page on that i want to disable right click when user click on any image it will go to login page after login i want eturn to gallery page with right click re-enable.

Answer (score 0):

Any user can prevent JavaScript from blocking the context menu, but the basic idea is use a boolean flag inside a function to enable and disable it.

```js
var isDisableRightClick = true;
document.body.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (evt) { 
    if (isDisableRightClick) evt.preventDefault();
});

document.getElementById("x").addEventListener("click", function(){
    isDisableRightClick = !isDisableRightClick;
});
```

```html
<button id="x">toggle</button>
<p>Filler</p><p>Filler</p><p>Filler</p><p>Filler</p><p>Filler</p>
```